# Git rebase: All conflicts fixed but git rebase --continue fails without naming any file causing the issue

Tags: git, rebase

I am rebasing my branch on master. This is a strange situation I have never encountered earlier. I resolved all conflicts and marked resolution by doing a `git add`. This is recognized by git and it tells me to `run "git rebase --continue"` but when I run that command, it responds with
`You must edit all merge conflicts and then mark them as resolved using git add`

Here is the console output of the above interaction, with irrelevant parts redacted. Note that `git status` output says `(all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")` but on running that command, there is a message with no hint about the issue.

```
%> git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto <commit-id>
Last commands done (49 commands done):
   pick <commit-id> ....
   pick <commit-id> ....
  (see more in file .git/rebase-merge/done)
Next commands to do (38 remaining commands):
   pick <commit-id> ....
   pick <commit-id> ....
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently rebasing branch 'branch-1' on '<commit-id>'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        ....

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        ....

%> git rebase --continue
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add

%> git --version
git version 2.35.1.windows.2
```

Comment: You need to stage the files where you fixed the commits to let git know the conflicts where fixed

Comment: As it says `You must edit all merge conflicts`, there must be some conflicting files in the section of `Changes not staged for commit`. Are there any files listed there starting with `both added`, `both modified`, `deleted by us`, etc.? If yes and you have resolved the conflicts, add the files before `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: @ElpieKay - See my "answer". There was one file listed in the section of `Changes not staged for commit` but it did not say anything like `both added`, `both modified`, `deleted by us`, etc. That was what was so puzzling.

Answer (score -1):

This was my bad. The file that was listed as `not staged for commit` did not have any conflicts, but it was a Java source file and what it did have were some extra characters at the end of a line. These were characters I had meant to type into a different window, but my cursor was in the IDE and they got added into this file instead.

Removing those extra unneeded characters fixed the issue, and I can continue now.